# Как используя цикл while вывести число Фибоначчи под заданным номером?

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа-фибоначчи

Нужна программа, которая будет вычислять n-ое число Фибоначчи. Число n, которое подается на вход программе, может принимать значения от 0 до 20. Использовать рекомендуется только цикл while.

```
n = int (input())
i = 1
s = 0
while 0 <= n <= 20:
    s += i
    i = s + i
    print (s)
```

Comment: А в чём суть вопроса, уточните, пожалуйста?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код, который Вы хотели бы модифицировать.

Comment: А что вам не  не нравится в вашем коде?

Comment: Часть 0<=n можно и нужно выкинуть.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал при работе с Фибоначчи делать список, потому что будет удобнее складывать каждый раз последние два числа. 
Создаю основной цикл (while True), чтобы можно было пользоваться неограниченное количество раз. Затем приём номера числа Фибоначчи в переменную 'n', затем создаю список, в котором будут хранится все числа Фибоначчи до нашего номера включительно. Далее создаю цикл 'while', который будет длится, пока размер нашего списка не станет равным нужному нам порядковому номеру числа Фибоначчи. В итоге вывожу последнее созданное число.

```
while True:
    n = int(input(': '))
    fib = [0, 1]
    while len(fib) <= n:
        fib.append(fib[-2]+fib[-1])
    print(fib[-1])
```

Comment: Хорошо, что тут максмум 20 чисел. А если потребуется найти 500-е? Создавать список на 500 элементов? Двух переменных будет достаточно - быстрее доступ и занимает меньше памяти.

Comment: @Эникейщик А если потребуется найти 500-е, то тогда и условие начальное было бы другое. По поводу быстрого доступа не факт, у вас каждый запрос будет за O(n) идти, а в случае со списком O(1). Но вот по памяти наоборот. Данное решение для запрашиваемой задачи вполне рабочее. P.S. Либо памятью жертвовать, либо временем, третьего не дано.

Comment: @Ildar Akhmetov  `каждый запрос будет за O(n) идти` - объясните, почему???

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov да, почему? И чо такое в данном случае n.

Comment: В данном случае n - это требуемое число. У вас будет n-2 операций сложения, что даёт O(n) затрат по времени.